# Post to wall on Facebook and twitter using c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook-c#-sdk

Facebook provide an API For developers to integrate other platforms. Now i'm using c# .net for web application. But i don't know how to integrate with in. guide me how Facebook use for c#.net

Thank you,

Comment: Check out [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). It is as simple as POST and GET web requests...

Answer (score 1):

You  can do with using [OAuth](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380635/Csharp-Application-Integration-with-Facebook-Twitt)

Or Use [Graph API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569920/Publish-a-post-on-Facebook-wall-using-Graph-API)

Comment: Which is the better one... What is the different between

Comment: You can refer that link's and choose best approaches your-self .